# Global phase and continuous symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

It is claimed that The symmetry of the wave function in quantum mechanics
\begin{align}
    \psi(\vec{x},t)\rightarrow e^{i\alpha}\psi(\vec{x},t)
\end{align}
forms a one-parameter set of transformations.

Can I say that it is continuous symmetry since the exponential essentially results in rotations in a Bloch sphere, and a global phase would not affect our measurement of a quantum state? Is $\{\alpha\}$ the set we're interested in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection of transformations that you have is indeed paramatrised by $\alpha$. Speaking from the math perspective, when people say that you have a continuous symmetry, they almost certainly mean that you have a representation of a Lie Group, in this case the Lie Group would be $U(1)$ - which is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. Note that this is connected to the identity, which is $\alpha = 0$ (this might also be included implicitly when people talk about continuous transformations).

I'm not sure why you bring up the Bloch Sphere though, the Bloch Sphere (also known as the Riemann Sphere), also known as $\mathbb{C}P^1$, is the space of states in a quantum system that is represented by a two-dimensional Hilbert space; so this is the space *after* you quotient by the phase transformation that you wrote in your question. Your phase transformation doesn't induce a rotation on the Bloch Sphere, because points on the Bloch Sphere are given by different physical states.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! For the time evolution of a given state in the Bloch sphere, can I think of the evolution as a rotation along the z-axis, so they are the same physical state but different by a global phase?

Comment: I agree with your final comment. And I think it is disputable to say that  we are speaking of a **continuous** symmetry here. A continuous  (Wigner) symmetry, in quantum physics,  is (a) a group representatation $\Gamma$ of a given topological group $G$ in terms of  (b) bijective maps from the space of rays $[\psi]$ to the space that (c) preserves the transition probabilities and (d) that is strongly  continuous. Here we have the trivial (constant) representation of $U(1)$ instead. That is nothing but the **trivial simmetry**.